# Using @Override with a super interface

Tags: java, interface

UPDATE : Back in the days, it was just a compilation level problem with maven.

The issue concerns the @Override annotation and super interfaces.

It's a simple as it gets really the problem is that the @Override annotation is not scoped up to the upper interfaces ...

Here is a bit of simple code to understand the problem :

```
public abstract interface CrudDao<T>
{
    void update(T bean);

    T get(Object... pk);

    void delete(Object ...pk);

    T create(T bean);
}



public interface BeanDao extends CrudDao<Bean>
{
    Bean moreSpecificGetMethod();
    void moreSpecificUpdateMethod();
}

public class BeanDaoImpl implements BeanDao {

    @Override
    public void update(Bean bean){}

    @Override
    public Bean get(Object... pk){}

    //... Rest of the methods 
}
```

The compiler says the methods should be created in the BeanDao interface. Why is it not resolving the methods from the super interface ?

Comment: Are you sure it is `public interface BeanDaoImpl` and not `public class BeanDaoImpl`?

Comment: Sorry, of course it's not public interface BeanDaoImpl but public class BeanDaoImpl, corrected it.

Comment: I'm using the latest 1.6 JDK with default compliance settings in eclipse.

Comment: Now with `BeanDaoImpl` being a non-abstract class, you cannot have methods without body... Also the methods need to be `public` Is that intentional to "simplify" the question?

Comment: Same code does not give any compilation error if you make the BeanDaoImpl as abstract and the methods as public..it works fine.

Comment: @Gepsens, I've read your edit. Check my answer; you might have your compliance level set to 1.5 and not 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler and the `@Override` annotation processor are just fine. During compilation with javac (on the command line), the following message is listed for the update method of `BeanDaoImpl` class:

> update(info.example.Bean) in info.example.BeanDaoImpl cannot implement
>   update(T) in info.example.CrudDao; attempting to assign weaker access
>   privileges; was public

and the reason is because the `update` method in CrudDao is in fact public. According to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.4):

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public.

And on making the `BeanDaoImpl.update` method public, the error message goes away. The same holds good for similar error messages from other methods.

There is also the problem with the Eclipse project settings. Just because you are using JDK 
1.6 to run Eclipse, you need not automatically have the compiler not complain about `@Override` annotation processing. You'll need to set the `Compiler compliance level` of the project to 1.6, in your `Java Compiler` panel of your project settings. Having a value of 1.5 will result in the Eclipse annotation processor complain about unimplemented methods, when in fact, you those methods have been implemented, but declared in a superinterface, as in your case.

The problem with the compiler compliance level settings is partly due to the initial [`@Override` specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) - it was restricted to superclasses alone and did not include interfaces as a supertype. This was fixed in Java 6, but [the documentation was not updated](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahe/entry/override_snafu). The compiler compliance level of 1.5 get the Eclipse annotation processor to treat `@Override` annotated methods as those requiring existence in the superclass, and not in a supertype.

Answer (score 0):

> public interface BeanDaoImpl implements BeanDao {
>
> ```
> @Override
> void update(Bean bean);
>
> @Override
> Bean get(Object... pk);
>
> //... Rest of the methods  }
> ```

Change the implements to extends. Interfaces don't implement other interfaces they extend them.

If you do this, the error you're referring to falls away.

Should be:

> public interface BeanDaoImpl **extends** BeanDao {
>
> ```
> @Override
> void update(Bean bean);
>
> @Override
> Bean get(Object... pk);
>
> //... Rest of the methods  }
> ```

Comment: `BeanDaoImpl` is a class not interface

Comment: I edited the mistake early on, I was working and just copy pasted the interface sorry about that. The IMPLEMENTATION is obviously an implementation of the interface and intended as such. Both methods are public and have body.

Answer (score 0):

The @Override Javadoc states.

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method
>   declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this
>   annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers
>   are required to generate an error message.

In your case we have an issue:

- Either it's an interface which you will need to `extends` (and not `implements BeanDao` and remove the `update`/`get` method), or
- It's a class (not abstract), which means you `implements BeanDao` and implement the overridden methods.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious correction to your posted code is this:

```
public class BeanDaoImpl implements BeanDao {
    @Override
    public void update(Bean bean) {}

    @Override
    public Bean get(Object... pk) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Methods need to be public and have a body.